# How we can read the value from file that is .txt file and store it value in ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, file-handling

Parse the notepad file data in ArrayList with Records of Student

Comment: Have you sorted out how you want to put the student's data into the txt file? Or are these files given already?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have:

1- You want to read a file line by line.

2- You want to create a student object for the data you obtained from each line.

3- You want to add the created object to the array list.

The solution's algorithm for each step respectively:

1- You can read a line as a string, and iterate it for each line using a loop until there is no other line.

2- You can parse the string you obtained in 1-st step. You can use .split(String delimiter) method of String class. This makes you able to split a string to an array of strings. It cuts the string from the indexes that there is a delimiter. For example, if you have the String "Hi,How,Are,You" and the Delimiter: "," then your new String array will be: {"Hi","How","Are","You"}.

Then you should think about how you convert a string formatted integer to an integer. e.g. "123" to 123. For that aim, you can use Integer.parseInt(String stringFormattedInteger).

3- You should use .add(Object o) method of ArrayList Template Class.

I suppose that you have a class **Student** with only *id* and *name* properties and a constructor taking *id* and *name* respectively.I also suppose you have such a format in the txt file:

(Student ID) (Student Name)

For Example:

1 Samantha Black

2 James Wizard

Then your code should be similar to this:

```
try{
    File file = new File("File.txt")
    FileReader fr=new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
    ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    String line;
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null)  
    {  
        int id = Integer.parseInt(line.split(" ")[0]);
        String name = line.split(" ")[1];
        Student s = new Student(id, name);
        students.add(s);

    }  
}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note: You may want to use the declaration of ArrayList outside of try block.